# "e_tooltip(formatter = )" how to display the interval instead of the average of the histogram column?

Tags: javascript, r, echarts, echarts4r

I have a histogram and the need to see not the average value of the histogram column (`2.9` on the picture), but its interval (`2.8-3.0`). How to do it?

Example code:

```r
iris %>% setDT() %>% 
    e_charts() %>%
    e_histogram(
        Sepal.Width,
        name = "histogram") %>%
    e_density(
        Sepal.Width,
        name = "density",
        y_index = 1) %>%
    # e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
```

What I see and what I want to see:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add this information, I've written a JS function that goes into the call for `e_tooltip`. There is only one element that I can't get dynamically—the row count for the data.

In the JS, where you see the number 32, that's the only information you would have to update in this code (other than the data in the `e_` functions).

Assumptions:

- the `binwidth` was not specified when calling for the histogram (`echarts4r` calculated bin width)
- the plot's first series is a histogram
- the plot's second series is density

Use the row count and this function to create the formatted tooltip your looking for.

```
ttFrm <- function(rowCt) { # use row count to call function
  htmlwidgets::JS(paste0("
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      h = data[0];            /* histogram */
      d = data[1];            /* density */

      bc = h.value[1];        /* bin count */
      ds = d.value[1];        /* density */

      /* bin width = count in bin / count in dataset / density */
      br = bc/", rowCt, "/ds/2;        /* bin span divided by two */
      bL = h.axisValue - br;  /* bin low */
      bH = h.axisValue + br;  /* bin high */
      
      return(
        '<b>' + bL + ' - ' + bH + '</b><br /><span style=\"color:' +
        h.color + ';\">●</span> ' + h.seriesName + 
        '<b style=\"padding-left: 2em;\">' + 
        bc + '</b><br /><span style=\"color:' +
        d.color + ';\">●</span> ' + d.seriesName + 
        '<b style=\"padding-left: 2em;\">' + 
        ds + '</b><br/>')
    }"))
}
```

Here's an example of how you can apply this formatting. (The call for the plot is from an `echarts4r` example plot.)

```
mtcars |>
  e_charts(elementId = 'chart') |>
  e_histogram(mpg, name = "histogram") |>
  e_density(mpg, areaStyle = list(opacity = .4),
            smooth = TRUE, name = "density", y_index = 1) |>
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "axis", confine = T, 
    textStyles = list(overflow = "breakall", width = 50),
    formatter = ttFrm(nrow(mtcars)))     # <<---- I'm new!!
```

[image]

Here's another example. Here I swapped out the data for the `iris` dataset.

```
iris |>
  e_charts(elementId = 'chart') |>
  e_histogram(Sepal.Width, name = "histogram") |>
  e_density(Sepal.Width, areaStyle = list(opacity = .4),
            smooth = TRUE, name = "density", y_index = 1) |>
  e_tooltip(
    trigger = "axis", confine = T, digits = 3,
    textStyles = list(overflow = "breakall", width = 50),
    formatter = ttFrm(nrow(iris)))
```

[image]